# UIScrollView Scroll issue in Xcode 7.2 size classes

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode7, size-classes

I have to design a screen for all the devices, so I have decide to use Size Classes + Auto Layouts in Xcode 7.2, but it has been 2 days to make it work, but all in vain.

I have googled and learnt a number of tutorials but even then not able to figure out what is wrong with my scroll view.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Dragged a UIScrollView into my UIViewController Class.
2. Resized scrollview to frame (0,0,600,600) viewcontroller's size.
3. Selected ScrollView and press on pin icon to add following constraints:
   Unchecked constraints to margins checkbox.
   Leading - 0, Trailing - 0, Top - 0, Bottom - 0.
4. Dragged a new UIView into scrollview and added following constraints:
   Unchecked constraints to margins checkbox.
   Leading - 0, Trailing - 0, Top - 0, Bottom - 0.
5. Now Dragged from my content view to main view(View controller's View) and selected "Center Horizontally in View" and "Center Vertically in view".
6. Now added some UI objects to my content view like UIImageView, UILabel, UItextFields and UIButtons and put constraints on them as well. My top most object is attached to content view's top and bottom object is not attached with content view's bottom as if I will do that it will shrink my objects to fit in the screen.

If I run this code everything is looking fine, except that on iPhone 4S I am unable to scroll.

I have tried a lot of things, but nothing worked for me. Could anyone help me on the same.

Comment: So it works on all other devices?

Comment: Yes It work, as on all other devices I do not need to scroll the content.

Comment: I've always just used uitableviewcontroller instead of scrollview. Scrollview always gives me problem and by using a one cell table view, it is a lot easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the height and a low priority.

1. Control drag the content view on to the view of the view controller as select the 'Equal Heights' option.

See around 35 secs at this video https://youtu.be/UnQsFlMGDsI?t=35s

Comment: I have tried, but not working. Could you please give me some example code.

Comment: Thanks Sana, I am able to figure this out using your point, but I have to change Height constraint priority to low(250) in the Size Inspector.

Comment: @RajenderKumar awesome.